# Make predictions on new data after training the GLM Lasso model

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, quanteda, lasso-regression

I have trained a classfication model on 13,000 rows of labels with lasso in r's glmnet library. I have checked my accuracy and it looks decent, now I want to make predictions for rest of the dataset, which is 300,000 rows. My approach was to label rest of the rows using the trained model. I'm not sure if that's the most effective strategy to do approximate labeling.

But, when I'm trying to label rest of the data, I'm running into this error:

```
Error in asMethod(object) : Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105
```

Even if I break the dataset to 5000 rows for predictions, I still get the same error.

Here's my code:

```
library(glmnet)
#the subset of original dataset
data.text <- data.text_filtered %>% filter(!label1 == "NA")

#Quanteda corpus
data_corpus <- corpus(data.text$text, docvars =  data.frame(labels = data.text$label1))

set.seed(1234)  

dataShuffled <- corpus_sample(data_corpus, size = 12845)

dataDfm <- dfm_trim( dfm(dataShuffled, verbose = FALSE), min_termfreq = 10)

#model to train the classifier
lasso <- cv.glmnet(x = dataDfm[1:10000,], y = trainclass[1:10000], 
    alpha = 1, nfolds = 5, family = "binomial")

#plot the lasso plot
plot(lasso)

#predictions
dataPreds <- predict(lasso, dataDfm[10000:2845,], type="class")
(movTable <- table(dataPreds, docvars(dataShuffled, "labels")[10000:2845]))
```

make predictions on rest of the dataset. This dataset has 300,000 rows.

```
data.text_NAs <- data.text_filtered %>% filter(label1 == "NA")

data_NADfm <- dfm_trim( dfm(corpus(data.text_NAs$text), verbose = FALSE), min_termfreq = 10)

data.text_filtered <- data.text_filtered %>% mutate(label = predict(lasso, as.matrix(data_NADfm), type="class", s="lambda.1se")
```

[image]

Comment: can you show the output of all of the code from `reprex::reprex(venue = "so")`? Then we will know where the error occurs. I'm guessing though it's in the call to `cv.glmnet()`, probably because your dfm gets huge when coerced to a dense matrix by this function.

Comment: Hi @KenBenoit, I have added an image of the output produced by reprex, wasn't sure any other way of sharing it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: From RStudio, the reprex output is copied to the clipboard automatically, and you can paste that directly into the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the `as.matrix(data_NADfm)` - this makes the dfm into a dense matrix, which makes it too large to handle.

Solution: Keep it sparse: either remove the `as.matrix()` wrapper, or if it does not like a raw dfm input, you can coerce it to a plain sparse matrix (from the **Matrix** package) using `as(data_NADfm, "dgCMatrix")`.  This should be fine since both `cv.glmnet()` and its `predict()` method can handle sparse matrix inputs.